# Any basic examples to help me understand that functions are objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and one thing I keep hearing is *"functions are objects"*.  Can you provide some examples for me to better understand this concept?

Comment: I would recommend reading MDN's guide on *[Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)*

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thanks andrew, can you recommend a similar guide for me to learn jquery?

Comment: jQuery's own website has a link to [some tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Here's some example code:

```
function Hello() {
    alert(Hello.world);
}

Hello.sayHello = Hello;
Hello.world = 'Hello, world!';

Hello.sayHello.sayHello.sayHello.sayHello.sayHello();
```

[Here's proof that it works, too.](http://jsfiddle.net/eJUWH/)

Notice how you can assign properties to the function, and assign it to itself and refer to it recursively. It's an object, like most other things in JavaScript, and you can do anything with it. If you've seen prototype inheritance before:

```
Function.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this.apply(null, arguments));
};

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

add.alert(1, 2); // Alerts 3
```

There's a lot here - a function literal, which is a function without a name in essence; prototypical inheritance; methods on functions; dynamic arguments; a function as `this`.

Comment: And that is why I hate Javascript. Thanks - I plan on using that as my Exhibit A. ;-)

Comment: @PeteMancini: Um... what is why? I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @PeteMancini - Which part? Lots of (if not all) OO languages let you do an equivalent of the `sayHello.sayHello.sayHello` example. The second example is perhaps a little confusing at first due to the two different `alert()` functions, but still I'm not seeing a problem that would somehow disappear if you used some other language...

Comment: @minitech and nnnnnn (can only notify one) It is not a problem, it is clarity. Other languages handle this with much more readability. I started programming with Javascript when it came out and it was a pretty simple but useful scripting language. This obtuse syntax is just awful to look at and read. My comment is only referring to aesthetics, which I consider to be an important component of a language. Perl, which I used regularly from '93 until a few years ago is even worse. Its not to say it isn't a very useful language as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example on jsBin: http://jsbin.com/enicaj/edit#source

Basically, since functions are objects, they can also have properties and methods.

EDIT: JavaScript inline.

```
function test(){
    return 'hello';
}
test.method = function(){
    return ' world';
};

document.write( test() + test.method() );
```

Outputs 'hello world';

Comment: Can you move the JavaScript into your answer? The answer won't be much use if jsbin goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a function:

```
function MyFunction()
{

}
```

but you can also write

```
var MyFunction = function()
{

}
```

you can call both using `MyFunction();`. There are different reasons for writing them each way, both have their benefits.

Example 1: the function is globally accessible even if you can it before it's defined. 
Example 2: the function is extendable as such.

```
var MyFunction = function()
{
    // private methods/properties for use inside object
    var privateProperty = 'privatevalue';
    var privateFunction = function()
    {
        return '';
    }

    // public methods/properties for use outside object
    this.propertyName = 'value';
    this.publicFunction = function()
    {
        return privateProperty;
    }
}
```

You can call the public data from the function just as you would an object.

```
var myobject = new MyFunction()
myobject.publicFunction();
// returns privatevalue;
```

But the `privateProperty` var you cannot access.

```
myobject.privateProperty // will returned undefined variable privateProperty
```

You can define properties and even methods/functions within the object (function).
That was very much a crash coarse but I hope it helps you understand it a bit more.

Comment: In your example, `this` does not refer to `MyFunction`, it refers to the global object (`window`).

Comment: you might wanna distinguish where's the public variable there. also, include a private function example.

Comment: @rampion I forgot the instantiate object. I wrote this quickly thanks for the heads up

Comment: In your amended example with `new`, `MyFunction` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sayHi = function() {
  console.log("hi!");
};

var anotherFunction = function(functionObject) {
  functionObject();
};
```

The function "sayHi" is passed as an object as an argument into the "anotherFunction" function and invoked.

```
anotherFunction(sayHi);
```

Use a javascript console like the one included in Chrome to observe this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fGYhv/).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest example of var- function with parameter.

```
var x = function(message){
    alert(message);
};

x('hello world');
x('hello again');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/g5AN2/3/)